# Null sent in front of fs.readFile string

Tags: json, node.js, post

#### Background

There is an existing Django app with postgres db. that cant be altered (for some reason) and the users want to automate uploading reports to it rather then the button they have to click to upload single reports (understandable)

I'm just writing a little Node.js script (it will attach to anonther node App) to to read a`.csv` file to a `json string` and send it via post to a db. just to test it sending before I do the automation.

#### Issue

The Issue is when I send the data there appears to be  hidden `?` at the start of the data

`?Number,Name,Date,Foo,Bar`

This is causing issues for the table reading it.

code I'm using

```
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('users.csv', utf8, function(err, data) {
    var sentData = JSON.stringify(data)
    request.post('/api/user/set_data').form(sentData)
})
```

Id guess it has something to do with the `"` as later in the data it also converts `(` `)` tp `%28` and `%29` but no hidden char at the end after the `\r\n"`

### Update

So having a little Fiddle with it if I 
    fs.readFile('users.csv', (err, data) => console.log(err, String(data)))

I can see `null 'Number,Name,Date,Foo,Bar` there are no nulls or empty values in the CSV

Comment: I don't think it's a question mark but a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Are you sure the file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: well... Id assume so. If I put anything other than 'utf8' I get nothing usable data wise

Comment: Have you tried to open the CSV file with an editor allowing you to see all characters like Notepad++ or else?

Comment: yea, had it open in visual studio code and looks like a perfectly normal csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a BOM causing issues

You could see the null in front of the first header. 
I did `npm i strip-bom`

and now have

```
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
const stripBom = require('strip-bom')

fs.readFile('users.csv', utf8, (err, data) => {
    var strippedData = stripBom(data)
    var sentData = JSON.stringify(strippedData)
    request.post(`${location}/set_data`).form(sentData)
})
```

and it all works great